# Template is not valid: Invalid template property or properties [1, 2, 3, DoNotify, 4, PassPercent, 5, 6]

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need someone to help me to modify this script. I am getting the following error when I try to create a stack in AWS.

> Template is not valid: Invalid template property or properties [1, 2, 3, DoNotify, 4, PassPercent, 5, 6]

I am not a scripter. I have found this script from online. I have googled it a lot but due to very low knowledge of coding I am unable to modify it

```js
{
  "DoNotify": "false",
  "PassPercent": "70",
  "1": {
    "Title": "Create a group with administrative permission.",
    "Points": "10",
    "Interval": "30",
    "Max": "30",
    "Assessments": {
      "API": "AWS",
      "Service": "IAM",
      "Method": "step_one_check",
      "Code": [
        "def step_one_check(handles,points)\n",
        "  iam = handles[0]\n",
        "  ret_hash = { :done => false, :score => 0 }\n",
        "  resp = iam.list_groups\n",
        "  groups = resp.groups\n",
        "  if groups!=[]\n",
        "    groups.each do |group|\n",
        "      group_name = group.group_name\n",
        "      resp1 = iam.list_attached_group_policies({group_name: group_name})\n",
        "      attached_policies = resp1.attached_policies\n",
        "      if attached_policies!=[]\n",
        "        attached_policies.each do |policy|\n",
        "          policy_name = policy.policy_name\n",
        "          if (policy_name.include? 'SystemAdministrator') || (policy_name.include? 'AdministratorAccess')\n",
        "            ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => points, :message => 'User group is created with administrative permission'}\n",
        "          else\n",
        "            ret_hash[:message] = \"Attached permissions is not Administrative permission\"\n",
        "          end\n",
        "         break if ret_hash[:done]\n",
        "        end\n",
        "      else\n",
        "        ret_hash[:message] = \"Administrative permission is not given to User group\"\n",
        "      end\n",
        "    end\n",
        "  else\n",
        "    ret_hash[:message] = \"User group is not created\"\n",
        "  end\n",
        " return ret_hash\n",
        "end"]
       }
     },

"2": {
    "Title": "Create IAM role with appropriate permissions.",
    "Points": "20",
    "Interval": "30",
    "Max": "30",
    "Assessments": {
      "API": "AWS",
      "Service": "IAM",
      "Method": "step_two_check",
      "Code": [
        "def step_two_check(handles,points)\n",
        "  iam = handles[0]\n",
        "  getScore = 0\n",
        "  putScore = 0\n",
        "  listScore = 0\n",
        "  ret_hash = { :done => false, :score => 0 }\n",
        "  resp = iam.list_roles\n",
        "  roles = resp.roles\n",
        "  if roles!=[]\n",
        "    roles.each do |role|\n",
        "      if role.assume_role_policy_document.include? 'ec2.amazonaws.com'\n",
        "        msg3 = 'Created an Amazon EC2 AWS Service role '\n",
        "        resp1 = iam.list_role_policies({role_name: role.role_name})\n",
        "        policies = resp1.policy_names\n",
        "        if policies!= []\n",
        "          policies.each do |policy|\n",
        "            permissions = iam.get_role_policy({role_name: role.role_name, policy_name: policy}).policy_document\n",
        "            if permissions.include? 's3'\n",
        "              if permissions.include? 'Get'\n",
        "                getScore = 5\n",
        "              end\n",
        "              if permissions.include? 'Put'\n",
        "                putScore = 5\n",
        "              end\n",
        "              if permissions.include? 'List'\n",
        "                listScore = 5\n",
        "              end\n",
        "            else\n",
        "              ret_hash[:message] = \"S3 permissions not found\"\n",
        "            end\n",
        "            break if ret_hash[:done]\n",
        "          end\n",
        "        else\n",
        "          ret_hash[:message] = \"Policies are not attached\"\n",
        "        end\n",
        "        points = getScore + putScore + listScore +5\n",
        "        if points == 20\n",
        "          ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => points, :message => 'Role created with all required permissions'}\n",
        "        end\n",
        "        if points > 0 and points < 20\n",
        "          ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => points, :message => 'Role created but some permissions are missing'}\n",
        "        end\n",
        "      else\n",
        "        ret_hash[:message] = \"Role is not Amazon ec2 service role\"\n",
        "      end\n",
        "      break if ret_hash[:done]\n",
        "    end\n",
        "  else\n",
        "    ret_hash[:message] = \"Amazon ec2 service role is not created\"\n",
        "  end\n",
        "  return ret_hash\n",
        " end"]
       }
     },

"3": {
      "Title": "Require Virtual MFA for administrator users.",
      "Points": "10",
      "Interval": "30",
      "Max": "30",
      "Assessments": {
        "API": "AWS",
        "Service": "IAM",
        "Method": "step_three_check",
        "Code": [
          "def step_three_check(handles,points)\n",
          "  iam = handles[0]\n",
          "  count = 0\n",
          "  arn = \"\"\n",
          "  ret_hash = { :done => false, :score => 0 }\n",
          "  resp = iam.list_users.users\n",
          "  if resp.count > 1\n",
          "    resp = iam.list_virtual_mfa_devices\n",
          "    virtual_mfa_devices = resp.virtual_mfa_devices\n",
          "    virtual_mfa_devices.each do |device|\n",
          "      arn = device.user.arn\n",
          "      if !arn.include? 'awsstudent'\n",
          "        count = count +1\n",
          "      end\n",
          "    end\n",
          "    if count == 1\n",
          "      ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => 5, :message => 'Enabled Virtual MFA device for first administrator users'}\n",
          "    elsif count == 2\n",
          "      ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => points, :message => 'Enabled virtual MFA device for both administrator user'}\n",
          "    else\n",
          "      ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => 0, :message => 'Virtual MFA device is not Enabled for administrator user'}\n",
          "    end\n",
          "  else\n",
          "    ret_hash[:message] = \"Administrator Users are not created yet\"\n",
          "  end\n",
          " return ret_hash\n",
          "end"]
         }
       },

  "4": {
      "Title": "Log all API calls.",
      "Points": "10",
      "Interval": "30",
      "Max": "30",
      "Assessments": {
        "API": "AWS",
        "Service": "CloudTrail",
        "Method": "step_four_check",
        "Code": [
          "def step_four_check(handles,points)\n",
          "  cloud_trail = handles[0]\n",
          "  ret_hash = { :done => false, :score => 0 }\n",
          "  resp = cloud_trail.describe_trails\n",
          "  trail_list = resp.trail_list\n",
          "  trail_list.each do |list|\n",
          "    trail_name = list.name\n",
          "    if !trail_name.include? 'qltrail-lab-'\n",
          "      ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => points, :message => 'Successfully Created CloudTrail to log all API calls'}\n",
          "    else\n",
          "      ret_hash[:message] = \"CloudTrail not created yet\"\n",
          "    end\n",
          "    break if ret_hash[:done]\n",
          "  end\n",
          " return ret_hash\n",
          "end"]
         }
       },

  "5": {
      "Title": "Create load balancers for web tier and app tier.",
      "Points": "20",
      "Interval": "30",
      "Max": "30",
      "Assessments": {
        "API": "AWS",
        "Service": "ElasticLoadBalancing",
        "Method": "step_five_check",
        "Code": [
          "def step_five_check(handles,points)\n",
          "  elb = handles[0]\n",
          "  resp = elb.describe_load_balancers.load_balancer_descriptions\n",
          "  if resp!=[]\n",
          "    appTireScore = 0\n",
          "    webTireScore = 0\n",
          "    internalScheme = 0\n",
          "    externalScheme = 0\n",
          "    total=0\n",
          "    resp.each do |load|\n",
          "      if load.load_balancer_name.downcase == 'web-elb'\n",
          "        webTireScore = 5\n",
          "        if load.scheme == 'internet-facing'\n",
          "          externalScheme = 5\n",
          "        end\n",
          "      end\n",
          "      if load.load_balancer_name.downcase == 'app-elb'\n",
          "        appTireScore = 5\n",
          "        if load.scheme == 'internal'\n",
          "          internalScheme = 5\n",
          "        end\n",
          "      end\n",
          "    end\n",
          "    total = appTireScore + webTireScore + internalScheme + externalScheme\n",
          "    if appTireScore == 5 && webTireScore == 5\n",
          "      if internalScheme == 5 && externalScheme == 5\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'ELB Created for both web and app tiers'}\n",
          "      elsif internalScheme == 5 && externalScheme == 0\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'Created 2 elb but scheme of web-elb is wrong'}\n",
          "      elsif internalScheme == 0 && externalScheme == 5\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'Created 2 elb but scheme of app-elb is wrong'}\n",
          "      else\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'app-elb and web-elb is created but scheme of both elb is wrong'}\n",
          "      end\n",
          "    elsif appTireScore == 5 && webTireScore == 0\n",
          "      if internalScheme == 5\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'app-elb is created with correct scheme, but failed to create web-elb'}\n",
          "      else\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'app-elb is created but scheme of app-elb is wrong and also failed to create web-elb'}\n",
          "      end\n",
          "    elsif appTireScore == 0 && webTireScore == 5\n",
          "      if externalScheme == 5\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'web-elb is created with correct scheme, but failed to create app-elb'}\n",
          "      else\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'web-elb is created but scheme of web-elb is wrong and also failed to create app-elb'}\n",
          "      end\n",
          "    else\n",
          "      ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => 0, :message => 'No valid ELB found'}\n",
          "    end\n",
          "  else\n",
          "    ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => 0, :message => 'Load balancer not created yet'}\n",
          "  end\n",
          "  return ret_hash\n",
          "end"]
         }
       },
       
  "6": {
      "Title": "Computing capacity for web and application tiers are auto scalable.",
      "Points": "30",
      "Interval": "30",
      "Max": "30",
      "Assessments": {
        "API": "AWS",
        "Service": ["AutoScaling"],
        "Method": "step_six_check",
        "Code": [
          "def step_six_check(handles,points)\n",
          "  auto_scaling = handles[0]\n",
          "  auto_scaling_groups = auto_scaling.describe_auto_scaling_groups.auto_scaling_groups\n",
          "  if auto_scaling_groups != []\n",
          "    isAppAutoDone = false\n",
          "    isWebAutoDone = false\n",
          "    webAutoScale = 0\n",
          "    webElb = 0\n",
          "    webMinScore = 0\n",
          "    webMaxScore = 0\n",
          "    appAutoScale = 0\n",
          "    appElb = 0\n",
          "    appMinScore = 0\n",
          "    appMaxScore = 0\n",
          "    total= 0\n",
          "    ret_hash = { :done => false, :score => 0 }\n",
          "      auto_scaling_groups.each do |group|\n",
          "        if group.auto_scaling_group_name.downcase == 'webtier'\n",
          "          isWebAutoDone = true\n",
          "          webAutoScale = 5\n",
          "          elbArray=group.load_balancer_names\n",
          "        if elbArray != []\n",
          "          elbArray.each do |elbName|\n",
          "            if elbName.downcase == 'web-elb'\n",
          "              webElb = 5\n",
          "            end\n",
          "          end\n",
          "        end\n",
          "          if group.min_size == 2\n",
          "            webMinScore = 3\n",
          "          end\n",
          "          if group.max_size >= 4\n",
          "            webMaxScore = 2\n",
          "          end\n",
          "        end\n",
          "        if group.auto_scaling_group_name.downcase == 'apptier'\n",
          "          isAppAutoDone = true\n",
          "          appAutoScale = 5\n",
          "          elbArray=group.load_balancer_names\n",
          "          elbArray.each do |elbName|\n",
          "            if elbName.downcase == 'app-elb'\n",
          "              appElb = 5\n",
          "            end\n",
          "          end\n",
          "          if group.min_size == 2\n",
          "            appMinScore = 3\n",
          "          end\n",
          "          if group.max_size >= 4\n",
          "            appMaxScore = 2\n",
          "          end\n",
          "        end\n",
          "        break if (isAppAutoDone && isWebAutoDone)\n",
          "      end\n",
          "      total= webAutoScale + webElb + webMinScore + webMaxScore + appAutoScale + appElb + appMinScore + appMaxScore\n",
          "      if total == 30\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'Both Auto scalling groups are created and configured successfuly'}\n",
          "      elsif total < 30 && total > 0\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'Auto scalling group is created, but not configured correctly'}\n",
          "      else\n",
          "        ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'No valid Auto scalling group is created'}\n",
          "      end\n",
          "  else\n",
          "    ret_hash = { :done => true, :score => total, :message => 'No valid Auto scalling group is created'}\n",
          "  end\n",
          " return ret_hash\n",
          "end"]
       }
     }
}
```